# How to modify/add year to the output of the week and month function of lubridate package?

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I'm trying to get week numbers. `lubridate`'s `month` function does the job, when i only one year data. But problem arises when I have more than one year of data.
Ex:

```
library(lubridate)
data$weeks <- week(data$Date)
data$months <- months(data$Date)
```

my data now looks like:

```
       Date    weeks    months
1   2017-01-01     1   January
2   2017-01-02     1   January
6   2017-01-06     1   January
7   2017-01-07     1   January
9   2018-01-09     2   January
10  2018-01-10     2   January
11  2018-01-11     2   January
12  2018-01-12     2   January
```

expected output(something like below) that distinguishes years:

```
       Date        weeks       months
1   2017-01-01     1-2017   January-2017
2   2017-01-02     1-2017   January-2017
6   2017-01-06     1-2017   January-2017
7   2017-01-07     2-2017   January-2017
9   2018-01-09     2-2018   January-2018
10  2018-01-10     2-2018   January-2018
11  2018-01-11     2-2018   January-2018
12  2018-01-12     2-2018   January-2018
```

I want to do something for `quarter` function also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use base R to get week and month name from `Date`. Read `?strptime`. To add quarters, we can use base R `quarters` function and `paste` it with year.

```
df$weeks <- format(df$Date, "%U-%Y")
df$months <- format(df$Date, "%B-%Y")
df$quarters <- paste(quarters(df$Date), format(df$Date, "%Y"), sep = "-")

df
#         Date   weeks       months quarters
#1  2017-01-01 01-2017 January-2017 Q1-2017
#2  2017-01-02 01-2017 January-2017 Q1-2017
#6  2017-01-06 01-2017 January-2017 Q1-2017
#7  2017-01-07 01-2017 January-2017 Q1-2017
#9  2018-01-09 01-2018 January-2018 Q1-2018
#10 2018-01-10 01-2018 January-2018 Q1-2018
#11 2018-01-11 01-2018 January-2018 Q1-2018
#12 2018-01-12 01-2018 January-2018 Q1-2018
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17167, 17168, 17172, 17173, 
17540, 17541, 17542, 17543), class = "Date"), weeks = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), months = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "January", class = "factor")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "6", "7", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: how to get quarters (like Jan 1st is in Q1 and July 1st is in Q3).

Comment: @Sharmas We can use `quarters` function to do that. I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for that. is there any function to get the number of week in a month a date belong to, not number of week in a year. for ex: May 17, 2017 is in 20th week of 2017 and in 3rd week of May. I want to know if there's a function that gives this number. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sharmas yes, you can use the answers mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199851/r-how-to-get-the-week-number-of-the-month

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can use `paste0` and, as you mentioned, `lubridate::year`:

```
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(weeks = paste0(weeks, "-", year(Date)),
         months = paste0(months, "-", year(Date)))

#        Date  weeks       months
#1 2017-01-01 1-2017 January-2017
#2 2017-01-02 1-2017 January-2017
#3 2017-01-06 1-2017 January-2017
#4 2017-01-07 1-2017 January-2017
#5 2018-01-09 2-2018 January-2018
#6 2018-01-10 2-2018 January-2018
#7 2018-01-11 2-2018 January-2018
#8 2018-01-12 2-2018 January-2018
```

---

To add quarters you can do:

```
df1 %>%  
  mutate(weeks = paste0(weeks, "-", year(Date)),
         months = paste0(months, "-", year(Date))) %>% 
  mutate(quarters = paste0(quarter(Date), "-", year(Date)))

#        Date  weeks       months quarters
#1 2017-01-01 1-2017 January-2017   1-2017
#2 2017-01-02 1-2017 January-2017   1-2017
#3 2017-01-06 1-2017 January-2017   1-2017
#4 2017-01-07 1-2017 January-2017   1-2017
#5 2018-01-09 2-2018 January-2018   1-2018
#6 2018-01-10 2-2018 January-2018   1-2018
#7 2018-01-11 2-2018 January-2018   1-2018
#8 2018-01-12 2-2018 January-2018   1-2018
```

The data:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17167, 17168, 17172, 17173, 
17540, 17541, 17542, 17543), class = "Date"), weeks = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), months = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "January", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`lubridate::week()` only returns week component of a date-time object. if you want to attach `lubridate::week` to `lubridate::year` do as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  Date = as.Date(c(
      "2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-06", "2017-01-07", "2018-01-09",
      "2018-01-10", "2018-01-11", "2018-01-12"
      ))
)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    weeks = paste0(lubridate::week(Date), "-", lubridate::year(Date)),
    months = paste0(base::months(Date), "-", lubridate::year(Date))
    ) -> df

df

        Date  weeks       months
1 2017-01-01 1-2017 January-2017
2 2017-01-02 1-2017 January-2017
3 2017-01-06 1-2017 January-2017
4 2017-01-07 1-2017 January-2017
5 2018-01-09 2-2018 January-2018
6 2018-01-10 2-2018 January-2018
7 2018-01-11 2-2018 January-2018
8 2018-01-12 2-2018 January-2018
```