# Rounding month end data using weekly split in R

Tags: r, date

Input table:

```
   Date             Qty
2017-01-01          234
2017-01-08          123
2017-01-15          445
2017-01-22          113
2017-01-29          674
2018-02-05          120
2018-02-12          921
2018-02-19          732
2018-02-26          634
2018-03-05          711
```

Expected table:

```
   Date             Qty
2017-01-01          234
2017-01-08          123
2017-01-15          445
2017-01-22          113
2017-01-29          708.28  #674+(120/7 * 2)
2018-02-05          85.71   #(120/7 * 5)
2018-02-12          921
2018-02-19          732  
2018-02-26          837.14  #634+(711/7 * 2)
2018-03-05          507.85  #(711/7 * 5)
```

In the above o/p table, the quantity belonging to the **first date** of the new month is expected to split to the **last date** of the past month using the weekly proportions.

Eg:

2017-02-26 had a quantity of 634 and 2018-03-05 had 711
So, the quantity 711 is split by 7 (#days in a week) i.e. 711/7 = 101.571 and the month of February has 28 days in general so 2 shares (#days left in February as the present date of that row is 2017-02-26) of 101.571 are added to the existing quantity of 2017-02-26, thus making it 634+(101.571*2) => 634+203.14 => 837.14 (as you can observe in the expected table). Similarly the remaining 2 shares are deducted from the 2018-03-05 and now it remains with 5 shares (#days of the first week of the present month as the present date of that row is 2018-03-05) ie 711/5 => 507.85 (as you can observe in the expected table).

Using **R** how should I generalise this situation?

Comment: So you need this done one rows that fall on last week of a month?

Comment: Yes, for the remaining number of days in that month and the other part of the proportion goes to the row having the first week of the month.

Comment: The example says it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this answer:

```
> library(dplyr)
> first_day_of_month_wday <- function(dx) {
+   day(dx) <- 1
+   wday(dx)
+ }
> fil <- ceiling((day(df$Date) + first_day_of_month_wday(df$Date) - 1) / 7)
> 
> df %>% mutate(Qty1 = case_when(fil > 4 ~ Qty + (days_in_month(df$Date) - day(Date)) * lead(Qty)/7, TRUE ~ Qty)) %>% 
+                           mutate(Qty1 = case_when(lag(fil) > 4 ~ Qty/7  * day(Date), TRUE ~ Qty1)) %>% select(-Qty) %>% rename(Qty = Qty1)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   Date         Qty
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 2017-01-01 234  
 2 2017-01-08 123  
 3 2017-01-15 445  
 4 2017-01-22 113  
 5 2017-01-29 708. 
 6 2018-02-05  85.7
 7 2018-02-12 921  
 8 2018-02-19 732  
 9 2018-02-26 837. 
10 2018-03-05 508. 
>
```

PS: Used first_day_of_month_wday function from [R: How to get the Week number of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199851/r-how-to-get-the-week-number-of-the-month).