# Finding the last day of 3rd week for each month in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a vector that contains dates. I want to find the dates which are the last day of the 3rd week for each month.

structure(c(18631L, 18632L, 18633L, 18634L, 18635L, 18638L, 18639L,
18640L, 18641L, 18642L, 18645L, 18646L, 18647L, 18648L, 18649L,
18651L, 18652L, 18653L, 18654L, 18655L, 18656L, 18659L, 18660L,
18661L, 18662L, 18663L, 18666L, 18667L, 18668L, 18669L, 18670L,
18673L, 18674L, 18675L, 18676L, 18677L, 18680L, 18681L, 18682L,
18683L, 18684L, 18687L, 18688L, 18689L, 18690L, 18691L, 18694L,
18695L, 18696L, 18697L, 18698L, 18701L, 18702L, 18703L, 18704L,
18705L, 18708L, 18709L, 18710L, 18711L, 18712L, 18715L, 18716L,
18717L, 18718L, 18722L, 18723L, 18724L, 18725L, 18726L, 18729L,
18730L, 18731L, 18732L, 18733L, 18736L, 18737L, 18738L, 18739L,
18740L, 18743L, 18744L, 18745L, 18746L, 18747L, 18750L, 18751L,
18752L, 18753L, 18754L, 18757L, 18758L, 18759L, 18760L, 18761L,
18764L, 18765L, 18766L, 18767L, 18768L), class = c("IDate", "Date"
))

I have tried to solve this using lubridate but could not succeed. I am sure someone should be able to figure it out quickly.

Comment: You should make clear what is considered a "week". Does it agree with the numbering used by `POSIXlt`? So if a month starts on a Saturday, how would you be answering this question? Show the steps in natural language and then show what efforts at coding you have made.

Comment: Expected output is "2021-01-22" "2021-02-19" "2021-03-19" "2021-04-16" "2021-05-21". These are the dates which are last date of 3rd week for each of the months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you define weeks in each month as stated by @IRTFM. However, here is one attempt at this using base R taking help from the function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28007793/3962914) if `d` is the vector of dates.

```
monthweeks <- function(x) {
  ceiling(as.numeric(format(x, "%d")) / 7)
}

d[monthweeks(d) == 3 & weekdays(d) == 'Friday']
#[1] "2021-01-15" "2021-02-19" "2021-03-19" "2021-04-16" "2021-05-21"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, this helps

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
tibble(v1, v2 = floor_date(v1, 'month'), v3 = week(v1) - 
         week(v2) + 1) %>% 
 filter(v3 == 3) %>% 
 group_by(v2) %>% 
 slice_max(n = 1, order_by = v1) %>%
 ungroup
```